# Dart Inheritance Clarification

Tags: dart, inheritance

I am learning Dart and am facing an issue with understanding the way inheritance works here.

I have 3 classes `Alphabet`, `A` which extends `Alphabet` and `B` which extends `Alphabet` and implements `A`. Something like this:

```dart
class Alphabet {
  void define() {
    print("this is an alphabet");
  }
}

class A extends Alphabet {
  void func1() {
    print("called func1");
  }

  void func2() {
    print("called func2");
  }
}

class B extends Alphabet implements A {
  @override
  void func1() {
    print("called B:func1");
  }

  @override
  void func2() {
    print("called B:func2");
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is this works, even though I haven't defined the `define()` function from `A`, the function that `A` inherits from `Alphabet`.

My questions are :

1. In class `B`, which `define()` function do I get, `A.define()` or `Alphabet.define()`?
2. And if the `define()` function that I get is from `Alphabet`, then doesn't it defeat the purpose of *implementing* a class? As class `A` has 2 of its own functions and one that it inherits from `Alphabet`. So, it should tell me to override 3 functions.

NOTE: When I remove `extends Alphabet` from the definition class `B`, it shows the expected behavior, saying that I need to implement the `define()` function. That makes sense.

Comment: (1) There is no A.define. you get Alphabet.define. (2) override is when you want to change the behavior you inherited from your base class.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `B extends Alphabet`, that means that `B` provides the interface of `Alphabet` and inherits the implementation of `Alphabet`.

When you write `B implements A`, that means that `B` provides the interface of `A` but does not use any of `A`'s implementation.

`B extends Alphabet implements A` does what you requested: it provides the interfaces of both `Alphabet` and `A` (and the interface of `A` is a superset of `Alphabet`'s), and it uses the implementation from `Alphabet` but not from `A`. `B.define()` therefore will call the `Alphabet.define` implementation.

> 2. And if the `define()` function that I get is from `Alphabet`, then doesn't it defeat the purpose of *implementing* a class? As class `A` has 2 of its own functions and one that it inherits from `Alphabet`. So, it should tell me to override 3 functions.

No.  If it worked that way, then it would defeat the purpose of `extends A`.  If you want to force `B` to override all of the functions provided by `A`'s interface, then simply write `B implements A`.